# "Over at the works" vs "At the works"

Tags: prepositions

Please read the text below.

> *When Arthur came home from the factory a little before noon he
>   shouted, "Stay out of my way till I wash! **There's been an accident
>   over at the works!**" Nobody answered. Mrs. Feare, the housekeeper, was
>   talking on the kitchen telephone so loudly that she could not hear
>   him, and his daughter was of course at school.*
>
> <sub>**"Carried Away" by Alice Munro**</sub>

What would differ if I replace **over at** with **at**?

What does **over** add?

Comment: I think he shouted that because he thought of "over at the works" the same way he might think of "over there", where "at the works" was thought of as a place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some 'compound prepositions' have very different meanings from their primary component, but *over at* is semantically indistinguishable from *at*. *Over at* may always be reduced to bare *at*. However, as FumbleFingers, the reverse is not true; *over at* can replace *at* only if *at* bears a spatial sense, not in uses like *at work* or *at all events* or *at a price of*.

*Over at* is a colloquialism, not used in formal written English, and I think its use is mostly a matter of rhythm. Note that in spoken English simple prepositions are usually unstressed, but in compound prepositions the first element usually takes more stress thatn the second, so when a compound preposition is used it that first element always has   at least secondary stress:

> There's been an **<sup>++</sup>**accident at the **<sup>++</sup>**works!
>   There's been an **<sup>++</sup>**accident **<sup>+</sup>**over at the **<sup>++</sup>**Works!

Sometimes, if it's a supplement, it even takes the same stress as the object:

> There's been an **<sup>++</sup>**accident — **<sup>++</sup>**over at the **<sup>++</sup>**works!

If there *is* a semantic component here, it may be that the compound preposition takes some of the emphasis off of the specific place and onto the more general notion of “not here but somewhere else”. But that's just a guess ...

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that ***over at*** always has the "spatial displacement" sense, which plain ***at*** doesn't necessarily have. Thus the default interpretation (or at least, *nuance*) for *"I was at work"* differs from *"I was **over** at work"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Good point. I will steal it.